# NGINX load balencer

Tags: nginx, load, load-balancing

We have setup nginx server and also trying to do the load balancing with 2 other servers.

The setup is: One main server (proxy server) and other two servers (which serves the request)

We have set of .css, .js and .php files. We want the main server to serve all the static files like, .css, .js and image files and only for the .php request we want forward the request to between the 2 serving servers in a load balanced way.

Plz guide me on how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
upstream backends {
    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;
}

server {

    location / {
        # your static configuration
        root /path/to/static/files;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # your proxy configuration
        proxy_pass http://backends;
    }

}
```

Documentation is a good start point.

- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html
- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/root
- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass
- http://nginx.org/r/alias
- http://nginx.org/r/try_files

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifics in the

```
location /abcd/admin {

 server backend1.example.com

}
```